# tableview contentsize not get updated, when changing NSLayoutConstraint's constant

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiscrollview, keyboard

I have added a bottom constraint on tableView, and I change constant of the constrain programmatically when keyboard appears. The tableview's frame resizes, but the contentSize is not updating, why? How can I force it to recalculate.

I have tried many approach.

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserverForName(UIKeyboardDidShowNotification, object: nil, queue:NSOperationQueue.mainQueue(), usingBlock: {(notification: NSNotification?) -> () in

    let keyboardSize = (notification!.userInfo![UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)!.CGRectValue().size
    self.bottomConstraint.constant = keyboardSize.height
    self.view.layoutIfNeeded()

    if let messageTableViewController2 = messageTableViewController, let messageViewSize2 = messageViewSize {

        /*var frame = messageTableViewController2.tableView.frame
        frame.size.height = messageViewSize2.height - keyboardSize.height - 44
        messageTableViewController2.tableView.frame = frame*/

        /*messageTableViewController2.tableView.beginUpdates()
        messageTableViewController2.tableView.layoutIfNeeded()
        messageTableViewController2.tableView.endUpdates()

        var frame = messageTableViewController2.tableView.frame
        frame.size.height = messageTableViewController2.tableView.frame.size.height
        messageTableViewController2.tableView.frame = frame*/

        /*let h = messageTableViewController2.tableView.contentSize.height - keyboardSize.height + 44
        println("messageTableViewController2.tableView.contentSize: \(messageTableViewController2.tableView.contentSize) h: \(h)")
        messageTableViewController2.tableView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(messageTableViewController2.tableView.contentSize.width, h)*/
        /*messageTableViewController2.tableView.setNeedsUpdateConstraints()
        messageTableViewController2.tableView.beginUpdates()
        messageTableViewController2.tableView.endUpdates()*/
    }
})
```

Comment: If I'm not wrong, you have to reload the cell to update the row height.

Answer (score 0):

`tableView.contentSize` does not change.

Since you update `bottomConstraint` of tableView. Only `tableView.frame` will be changed. but `contentSize` property will be the same.

`tableView.contentSize` will be updated, when cell in tableView change. For example, insert, delete, reload.